# Integral $I=\int_{-2}^{1}-\frac{4}{2x^3 \cos{x}+2}\ \mathrm dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following definite integral:
$$I=\int_{-2}^{1}-\frac{4}{2x^3 \cos{x}+2}\ \mathrm dx.$$

The approximate value of the integral is $-7.14725$. 
Neither Mathematica, nor Wolfram Alpha could not find a closed form, and I have no idea how to proceed. Does a closed form exist, even one using non elementary functions?

Comment: Why didn't you write
$$I=-\int_{-2}^{1}\frac{2}{x^3 \cos{x}+1}\ \mathrm dx\ ?$$

Comment: I would be surprised by a closed form.

Comment: Why do you need a closed form?